# How do I remove the metal panel that covers the range broiler igniter?

Tags: range

I need to remove the upper metal panel on my DCS-RGU-366-N range to access the broiler igniter for replacement.  I have already removed the screws that appear to hold it on, but although it will move downward slightly, it seems stuck at one place at the top of the panel.  How do I get it totally removed?  Also, what all is under that panel besides the broiler igniter?

Comment: Have you searched the internet for replacement parts? Most sites that I've found with replacement parts also have exploded drawings showing where all the clips, screws, etc. are located, some even have videos showing how to disassemble the item and reassemble it. It'll also show you what else is under that panel.

Comment: I looked that part up and it has a piezo electric igniter, that and the thermocouple that the flame hits and of corse the jet for the gas, are you sure it is that side and not the high voltage module? I have found the module to be bad most of the time. Not the same model of stoves but the piezo type different brands the high voltage module is usually the bad part.